# Any solution for @JsonFormat issue with Date type

Tags: java, json, date, jackson, fasterxml

I have a property with type `Date` and input for this field would be like `2020-11-08T10:00:00+05:30`.
When I get this object in `Json` response it is not giving in same format. I am trying to accomplish this using `@JsonFormat` but I saw there is some issue with this approach from below link

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1266

This is how I have date field.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")
private Date startDate;
```

Is there any solution to accomplish or I should go with `Calendar` type and add custom `deserialization` like below.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
private Calendar startDate;
```

Comment: I recommend that you neither use `Date` nor `Calendar`. Both of those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. It seems from your string format that `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) will be the right class for your needs.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the reply. I agree with your point but It is existing code from long time so I am trying to achieve it with `Date` type to not to change anything else. Could you let me know if there is any solution with `Date` ? I will try with OffsetDateTime if there is no solution with `Date`

Comment: Sorry, I haven’t got the experience, so can’t tell. But I have got it to work with `OffsetDateTime` and Jackson.